# How to tackle situation when client do not respond for an escro project

Tags: client-support, difficult-client

I have started a project with a client where the deal was to upfront an amount of money, then he will do escrow for all of the remaining money, with it being released after completion of the project. I have started working on the project already.

Initially, I sent the design to him he said the design is fine for him.  I have sent many builds for getting feedback, generally every 3 to 4 days. But, he didn't provided any response, and I continued working, by thinking no feedback means client is good with what is going on.

I just provided the last build (Complete) a week ago, but now client does not come online. Before, his site was down for a week, so I contacted him and he had responded and solved the issue. However, I am now not able to communicate with him. **What could be done now?**

**Also, if the client comes back and if he suggest a big change, what should I do?** As you all know, if a change is given after completion of the app, it will require lot effort to fix, rather than if it would be specified at the development time itself.

Answer (score 5):

If a client doesn't respond after sending the first build then you should not continue with the project. You stated the problem yourself:

> also If client comes back and what if he suggest a big change ? as you all know if a change is given after completion of the app it will require lot effort to fix rather than if it would be specified at the development time it self.

If you are running out of time then it's because of him and not you. And it's also strange that he responded fast when his site was down but not when you are sending him messages. That means he's not that busy or away or something.

And also, a client should respond to messages or at least tell you to do it how you think it's best. There is no " no feedback means client is good with what is going on". A good client always has 1-2 minutes to reply to a message.

If he comes back to suggest a big change then I suggest you just do it. It's pretty much your fault because you have done work without him agreeing to it. And next time just don't do any work without feedback to avoid these kind of situations.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when i sent the design he said he is good with design, and in the first buld he messaged that this is the missing, at that time I specified to him that the work is in progress, and then no feedback. and from escro company can i get my money if he do not respond ?

Comment: OK, so he didn't give you any message after the first one. Well, in any case, the escro company should give you the money after some time with no response. At least that is how most companies work. And if you have the work to show them then you should be fine.

Comment: And just in case, you should ask them or review their policy for such situations.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have proof the client actually placed funds into the escrow account?  If not, I definitely would have not started the project without that proof.  If so, then you might contact the escrow company and determine what their process is for a dispute.  Keep copies of all of your communications with the client, and a copy of your signed contract with them (you DO have one, don't you?) and then if it were me, I'd send one more notice to your client... a notice that sets a deadline for responding with reasonable changes, and/or release of escrow funds after which you will be filing a dispute over the unreleased funds with the escrow company or whoever they designate to act as mediator in situations like this.

By the way, no comments from a client is not always a good thing.  In your case, I would have refused to continue with the work unless they signed off on each of the deliverables phases.  I don't know whether not having that approval for work already done will help or hinder your ability to get the money you are owed.